# MVC special routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC project where i need to define some custom routes.  Similar to what you see for posts on Wordpress where the route is of the form `postid-postname`:

```
12-i-am-post
```

I know how to do something like `postid/postname`:

```
12/i-am-post.
```

But how do I make a route that combines the two, such as:

```
mywebsite.com/12-postname-is-her
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PostRoute", // Route name
    "{controller}/{id}-{postName}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, postName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);


public ActionResult Index(int id, string postName)
{
    return View();
}
```

Should work for the following request http://localhost/Post/1-MyPostName

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple hyphens you won't be able to use it as a delimiter/separator, unless you want it to always match the first occurrence.  Your best bet is to do a catchall `{*path}` and parse the value in your controller.

Comment: What's going wrong. the ID is always come first and the name is later and posname have no matter when ID is unique and can be used to identify the Post.